# parse json with ant

Tags: json, ant

I have an ant build script that needs to pull files down from a web server.  I can use the "get" task to pull these files down one by one.  However, I'd like to be able to get a list of these files first and then iterate over the list with "get" to download the files.  The webserver will report the list of files in json format, but I'm not sure how to parse json with ant.

Are there any ant plugins that allow for json parsing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [<script>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) task to [run JavaScript to decode your JSON](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php).

Comment: Be careful though, as writing JSON from the rhino plugin seems to be problematic. There is no JSON.stringify, and NativeJSON.stringify() appears to be inaccessible from the plug-in. I'm thinking of switching to jython because of this.

Answer (score 9):

I used Dave's suggestion above and it worked out pretty well. Here's what I came up with:

(Note, I ripped this out of my actual build file and tried to remove anything specific and just leave the example parts, so forgive me if it's missing anything or whatever, but it should give you an idea of how this works).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="jsonExample" default="all">
<target name="all" depends="example" />

<target name="example">

<!-- This uses Rhino - an Open Source implementation of JavaScript written in Java -
     to parse JSON. -->
<script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[

    importClass(java.io.File);
    importClass(java.io.FileReader);
    importClass(java.io.BufferedReader);
    importClass(java.io.FileWriter);
    importClass(java.io.BufferedWriter);

    var file = new File("/path/to/myJSON.js");
    fr = new FileReader(file);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    // Read the file we just retrieved from the webservice that contains JSON.
    var json = br.readLine();

    // Evaluate the serialized JSON
    var struct = eval("(" + json + ")");

    // Get the data from 
    var value = struct.data.VALUE;

    echo = example.createTask("echo");
    echo.setMessage("Value = " + value);
    echo.perform();

    ]]>
</script>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: CodeDomProvider for 'javascript' could not be created. Could not load type 'javascript' from assembly 'NAnt.DotNetTasks, Version=0.92.4543.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe because you're using NAnt, and this example was for Ant. I have no idea if javascript is supported in NAnt, but if you're building .NET, you're not going to be able to use any of the java.io stuff.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like NAnt supports javascript. In the end, I used PowerShell ConvertFrom-Json and it works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the macro I use to load json-properties.

```
 <macrodef name="json-properties">
     <attribute name="jsonFile"/>
     <sequential>
         <local name="_jsonFile"/>
         <property name="_jsonFile" value="@{jsonFile}"/>
         <script language="javascript">//<![CDATA[
             var json = new Packages.java.lang.String(
                 Packages.java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(
                     Packages.java.nio.file.Paths.get(project.getProperty("_jsonFile"))), "UTF-8");
             var properties = JSON.parse(json);
             for(key in properties) {
                 project.setProperty(key, properties[key]);
             }
     //]]></script>
     </sequential>
 </macrodef>
```

Comment: I liked this solution. However, I did not find a way to access the values of the properties, since all I would get back was: [object Object]. What helped was this:

`for(var key in properties) { project.setProperty(key, JSON.stringify(properties[key])); }`

Comment: ```{"foo":"1","bar":2"}```
```<echo message="${foo} ${bar}"/> ```